# Identify the deleted tweets from tweepy data

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a large tweets data streamed from tweepy. I want to retrieve the *deleted tweets* from that data.
Each tweet extracted from tweepy has a unique id, I used ***API.get_status(ID)*** method to retrieve the tweet, if the tweet is retrieved succesfully then it is not deleted else if it raises an exception I assume that the tweet is deleted.

```
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)        
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth) 
x = 570345457618006016
try:
    tweet = api.get_status(x) 
except Exception, e:
    print "deleted Tweet", tweet.text
    pass
```

But in this method, I often get the tweets which are not related due the raised exception:

```
Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/show.json?id=570500313653776384 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1fce3810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Can anyone suggest a method that can help me identify the deleted tweets from my corpus

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing the same way with *every* exceptions. You should deal differently with the ones that are made by deleted tweets, and the ones that are caused by the rate limit. However, rather than dealing with two kinds of exceptions, you could just avoid hitting the rate limit.

Hitting the limit too often will likely get your application blocked, you should pause before you hit it. You are allowed to make 180 requests every 15 minutes: sleep for 15 minutes every 180 requests, and your code will work fine.

Comment: You can also set [`wait_on_rate_limit`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L44) to `True` to have tweepy automatically wait for the necessary amount of time.

Comment: I've already encountered problems with this option, mainly it doing nothing. Maybe I did something wrong, maybe there was a problem with Tweepy. As a result, I don't trust it.